# as3 TypeError #2007 Parameter text must be non-null can't fix

Tags: php, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have comment box project. As3+php based project.And have #2007 Error.Try to fix but can't  do anything.If can help it would be very helpful.Eror part like this:

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter text must be non-null.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at comment2_fla::mc_1/completeHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

```
var variables_re:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var varSend_re:URLRequest = new URLRequest("guestbookParse.php");
varSend_re.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend_re.data = variables_re;

var varLoader_re:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader_re.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader_re.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler_re);

function completeHandler_re(event:Event):void{
    if(event.target.data.returnBody==""){
       gbOutput_txt.text = "no data";
       } else {
           gbOutput_txt.condenseWhite = true;
           gbOutput_txt.htmlText = "" + event.target.data.returnBody;

       }
}

variables_re.comType = "requestEntries";
varLoader_re.load(varSend_re);
```

**second part of code:**

```
msg_txt.restrict = "ığüşöç A-Za-z 0-9";
name_txt.restrict = "ığüşöç A-Za-z 0-9";

var errorsFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
errorsFormat.color = 0XFF0000;
processing_mc.visible = false;

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("guestbookParse.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeHandler);

function completeHandler(event:Event):void{ 
    processing_mc.visible = false;
    name_txt.text = "";
    msg_txt.text = "";
    status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg;
    gbOutput_txt.condenseWhite = true;
    gbOutput_txt.htmlText=""+event.target.data.returnBody;



}

submit_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ValidateAndSend);

function ValidateAndSend(event:MouseEvent):void{

    if(!name_txt.length){
        status_txt.text = "İsminizi Girin";
        status_txt.setTextFormat(errorsFormat);
    } else if (!msg_txt.length){
        status_txt.text = "Yorum Girin";
        status_txt.setTextFormat(errorsFormat);
    }else{
        processing_mc.visible = true;

        variables.comType = "parseComment";
        variables.userName = name_txt.text;
        variables.userMsg = msg_txt.text;

        varLoader.load(varSend);
        status_txt.text = "Yorumunuz Eklendi...";
    }
}
```

**and php part:**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("yorum") or die (mysql_error());

if ($_POST['comType'] == "parseComment") {

    $name = $_POST['userName'];
    $location = $_POST['userLocation'];
    $comment = $_POST['userMsg'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestbook (name, post_date, comment, location) 
        VALUES('$name', now(),'$comment','$location')")  
        or die (mysql_error());

    $body = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY post_date DESC"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $post_date = $row["post_date"];
        $comment = $row["comment"];
        $location = $row["location"];

        $comment = stripslashes($comment);
        $name = eregi_replace("&#39;", "'",  $name);
        $location = eregi_replace("&#39;", "'",  $location);
        $comment = eregi_replace("&#39;", "'", $comment);

        $post_date = strftime("%b %d, %y", strtotime($post_date));

        $body .= '<u><b><font color="#790000">' . $name . '</font>    |    <font color="#9B9B9B">' . $location . '</font>      |      <font color="#9B9B9B">' . $post_date . '</font></b></u>
        <br />
        '.$comment.'
        <br />
        <br />
        ';
    }
    mysql_free_result($sql);
    mysql_close();


     echo "return_msg=Entry has been added successfully $name, thanks!&returnBody=$body";
     exit();

} 

if ($_POST['comType'] == "requestEntries") {

    $body = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY post_date DESC"); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
        $id = $row["id"];
        $name = $row["name"];
        $post_date = $row["post_date"];
        $comment = $row["comment"];
        $location = $row["location"];
        $comment = stripslashes($comment);

        $post_date = strftime("%b %d, %y", strtotime($post_date));

        $body .= '<u><b><font color="#790000">' . $name . '</font>    |    <font color="#9B9B9B">' . $location . '</font>      |      <font color="#9B9B9B">' . $post_date . '</font></b></u>
        <br />
        '.$comment.'
        <br />
        <br />
        ';
    }
    mysql_free_result($sql);
    mysql_close();
    echo "returnBody=$body";
    exit();
} 
?>
```

Comment: I added some possible fixes,you just need to use a default value if the message is nll or undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you try to do something like

```
textInput.text=null;
```

I think this is the line with the problem

```
status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg;
```

Try first to check if that value you are setting to the text property is not null or undefined.

To fix you can do

```
status_txt.text = event.target.data.return_msg?event.target.data.return_msg :""
```

or

```
var message:String= event.target.data.return_msg;
if(!message) message="";
 status_txt.text =message;
```

Edit 2:
Try this

```
var message:String=event.target.data;
status_txt.text =message;
```

You will have to parse this message string, if is empty or if an expected result and display what you want to display.

Comment: I think I have problem about Php part.Because I can't add data to database.when .swf working I can enter text to text fields but I  see php code parts in comments pannel and cant't see any of entering comment.

Comment: It could be, I think my answer solves yur original problem. A suggestion on debugging your PHP, first test your PHP code from a browser (use GET maybe if is easy then when all works change back to POST) and try to echo any mysql error before exiting from the php script. Test small parts so is easy and echo status messages so you know what was executed. Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont know php coding but I'll try to fix.Thx for help